# c++ template - More than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Why did only the last invocation of max raise error?

> error C2668: 'max': ambiguous call to overloaded function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 t1, T2 t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}

template<typename RT, typename T1, typename T2>
RT max (T1 a, T2 b)
{
return b < a ? a : b;
}

int main()

    max<long double>(4.5, 4);
    max<double>(4.5, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did some research.  For  max<long double>(4.5, 4); the instantiation results are max<long double, long double, int> and <long double, double, int> and for max<double>(4.5, 4), the instantiation results are both <double, double, int>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given `max<long double>(4.5, 4);`, for the 1st `max` its 1st template parameter `T1` is specified as `long double`, `T2` is deduced from `4` as `int`. For the 2nd `max` `RT` is specified as `long double`, `T1` is deduced as `double` and `T2` is deduced as `int`. Then the 2nd one wins in overload resolution because it's an exact match while the 1st one requires implicit conversion from `double` to `long double`.

On the other hand, given `max<double>(4.5, 4);`, for the 1st `max` `T1` is specified as `double`, `T2` is deduced as `int`. For the 2nd `max` `RT` is specified as `double`, `T1` is deduced as `double` and `T2` is deduced as `int`. They're both exact match.